# Google Sheets - Group two columns containing duplicates, filter based on third column containing specific text

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to group together data containing duplicate information in two columns - **date** & **email** - and filter based on what is contained in a third column, **sku**.

**Requirements:**

1. Unique values only
2. Find/group by duplicates in A and C
3. Always filter out ADD-ON
4. If the sku contains BUNDLE then return that 1 row, otherwise return all rows

**What I have tried:**

I have a simple working formula to filter out ADD-ON, cell M3 in Google Sheet.

```
=FILTER(A3:C, NOT(REGEXMATCH(B3:B, "ADD-ON")))
```

A second formula, cell Q3 in Google Sheet, is able to return the first line of each duplicate block, but that assumes the data is always sorted - instead it should only return the row containing BUNDLE.

```
=SORTN(A3:C,99^99,2,1, TRUE, A3:A&C3:C,FALSE)
```

I haven't been able to find another example that I can edit to do exactly what I want, even after extensive searching.

**The data:** [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bjQIH1HNAqS2nD6bao3jjSKXKo8HqCEac50Q5AZPdEI/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: table data wouldn't load]

Answer (score 0):

See this formula in cell G2 on the MK_Help tab:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(SORTN(QUERY({A3:C,A3:A&C3:C,REGEXMATCH(B3:B,"BUNDLE")},"where not Col2 contains 'ADD-ON' order by Col5 desc",0),9^9,2,4,1,1,1),9^9,3)
```

It's a tricky problem, but using QUERY() helps take care of two of the requirements at once.  we can pre-sort the results by the REGEXMATCH() column to get the BUMBLE's to the top if there are any for every dupe.

Comment: Thank you, it's very close, though only the first row from the first group (2022-06-09 9:09:09 PRODUCT-1 c1@example.com) is displayed, instead of the five rows (PRODUCT-1 through PRODUCT-5) expected